# Is List<T> is serializable by default when T is serializable?

Tags: wcf, serialization

there is a data contract (say, `EmployeeView`) in my WCF service. I have decorated it with `Serializable` attribute, and all members are marked as `DataMember`
A method in the WCF is returning `List<EmployeeView>`.
When I execute this method through WCF Test client or MVC app, it gets executed successfully, but while transferring result it is giving an error of `The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly`. Is `List<EmployeeView>` not serialized though `EmployeeView` is marked as serialized?

Further to add, if I execute an OperationContract returning only "EmployeeView" it gives me different error saying, `The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy` This is making things strange, because other operations returning string, etc are working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It depends on whether the concrete implementation of List is Serializable.

You also need to stop using the terms 'serialized' and 'Serializable' as though they mean the same thing. They don't.